# Prove if $(a,b) = d$ , then $(a/d , b/d)= 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have proved this a few ways but now I have to prove it using FTA and have hit a roadblock. Please advise!

Prove if $(a,b) = d$ , then $(a/d , b/d)= 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a = p_{1}^{e_{1}}p_{2}^{e_{2}}...p_{n}^{e_{n}}$ and $b = p_{1}^{g_{1}}p_{2}^{g_{2}}...p_{n}^{g_{n}}$  with $p_{i}$ prime divisor of $a$ or $b$ (some $e_{i}$ or $g_{i}$ might be zero but not at the same time).

Then $d = (a,b) = p_{1}^{min(e_{1},g_{1})}p_{2}^{min(e_{2},g_{2})}...p_{n}^{min(e_{n},g_{n})}$.

Then for each $p_{i}$ in $a/d,b/d$ will have $e_{i}=0$ or $g_{i}=0$.

It follows that $(a/d,b/d) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it now!

Answer (score 0):

If $gcd(a,b) = d$, then we can write that there exist integers $x,y$ uniquely such that $ax+by=d$ which means $\frac{a}{d}x+\frac{b}{d}y=1$, that is $gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})=1$

Comment: The OP specifically notes that they want to prove this fact using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: Yes please! Thank you for the answer but I definitely need to use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic!